# Removing UITextField gesture recognizers. How Legal is this in apple's rule book?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I am dealing with a `UITextField` where I want to prevent user from editing inbetween a string which is usually done using the longpress cursor moving loupe present inside a textfield.

I am trying to prevent that from happening by removing all gesture recognisers in the textField in `-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recogZ in textField.gestureRecognizers)
        {
            [textField removeGestureRecognizer:recogZ];
        }
```

or by removing the specific culprit, a gesture recognizer that goes by UIVariableDelayLoupeGesture

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recogZ in textField.gestureRecognizers)
        {
            if ([NSStringFromClass(recogZ.class) isEqualToString:@"UIVariableDelayLoupeGesture"])
            {
                [textField removeGestureRecognizer:recogZ];
            }
        }
```

Although both methods work properly, I have my doubts over using such technique. Is there any other better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to suppress moving cursor backwards, or you just wanna stop show copy/paste options that appears?

Comment: You can use setEditing = NO

Comment: @srinivasn editing is read-only property.

Comment: @hris.to yes i only want to suppress moving cursor backwards. And i forgot to mention the above pair of code actually work perfectly (updated OP)

Comment: I don't think any Apple tester will notice this special behaviour therefore you'll be probably perfectly fine to ship. Although you could consider my answer below to see if you could make use of it, as it is the recommended way of doing such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
-(BOOL)shouldChangeTextInRange:(UITextRange *)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

and just return NO when you don't like the range(it's not the end)? That way you could even pop an alert to user saying hey you are trying to write/delete at the middle of the text which is illegal.

Comment: Allowing the user use the editing loupe to go back where they will fail at inserting text will only be annoying and defeat the purpose of the loop appearing at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In at least one of the WWDC videos, I believe one about UIScrollView 2013, the Apple engineer talks about replacing a default UIScrollView gesture recognizer in order to do something a bit more customized.  I'm sorry I can't be more specific.  However, I don't think that Apple has a problem with you modifying an existing gesture recognizer.  I myself have added a number of new gestures to a scrollView in my apps, and that's not a problem so I don't see why yours would be.

Of course, if your change makes the Apple reviewer confused, then they might reject it because they think it is a bug or bad UX.